# Potential problem with a proof involving Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, riemann-integration

**My Question**

Is there a problem with this proof(red underlined part)? I do apologize for the use of images.

I believe that $\alpha$ is allowed to be discontinuous at $v_i$ and $u_i$ as we are only concerned about continuity at $d_i$ points.

**The Theorem**

[image]

**Counter example**

[image]

The equation $\alpha(t) - \alpha(d_i) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^{m+1}}$ holds as

for any $t\in(u_i,v_i)$ and letting $ d_i \in(u_i,v_i)$ and $\epsilon > 0,$

$|\alpha(t) - \alpha(d_i)| = |2-2| = 0 < \frac{\epsilon}{2^{m+1}}$

Now let $\epsilon = 1$ which is allowed as above should hold for any $\epsilon >0$.

thus $0< \frac{\epsilon}{2^{m+1}} < 1$.

Note: $0< \frac{\epsilon}{2^{m+1}}*2 = \frac{\epsilon}{2^{m}} <2$

But now $\alpha(v_i) - \alpha(u_i) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^m} < 2$ is not true as:

$\alpha(v_i) - \alpha(u_i) = 3-1 = 2$

thus $\alpha(v_i) - \alpha(u_i) > \frac{\epsilon}{2^m}$ which is a contradiction to $\alpha(v_i) - \alpha(u_i) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^m}$

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the proof does not not work as it is presented. Fortunately it can be easily repaired.

The purpose of the proof is to find $u_i, v_i$ such that $u_i < d_i < v_i$ and $\lvert \alpha(u_i) - \alpha(v_i) \rvert < \varepsilon/2^m$.

Take $u_i, v_i$ as in the proof in your question. Now choose $\bar u_i, \bar v_i$ such that $u_i < \bar u_i < d_i < \bar v_i < v_i$. Then for $t \in [\bar u_i, \bar v_i]$
$$\lvert \alpha(t) - \alpha(d_i) \rvert < \varepsilon/2^{m+1}$$
and we conclude
$\lvert \alpha(\bar u_i) - \alpha(\bar v_i) \rvert < \varepsilon/2^m$.

Thus we can replace the original $u_i, v_i$ by $\bar u_i, \bar v_i$.